# is it possible to have many sub-domains with the code in the root folder

Tags: php, web, dns, subdomain

i am developing a website. where in user would be asked to select their country( like USA, UK, Australia & Canada in the websites landing page.

i am planning to create a sub-domain for each country. Now my query is,

> is it possible to run the website with
>   these 4 sub-domain with the code and
>   data bases in the main ROOT FOLDER

.

OR

> do we need to install the code
>   separately in all sub-domains and
>   create the separate Data bases

.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gourav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can so this with a .htaccess file which redirects to the correct part of the script when they come from any sub domain.

Checkout this page as is has a similar problem and solution you have:

http://blog.gwebtools.com/apache-htaccess-subdomain-redirect-rules/

Extract:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#redirect gwebtools.com to www.gwebtools.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www..*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*).(com|com/)
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#if subdomain pt or whois and folder port-scanner redirect to pt.gwebtools.com/scanner-porta, with parameters
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(pt|whois)\.gwebtools\.com
RewriteRule ^port-scanner/* http://pt.gwebtools.com/scanner-porta$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Some information about .htaccess and some info so you can understand what the above code does: http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

Or you can do it in php like this tutorial:

http://php4every1.com/tutorials/multi-language-site/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ... if possible, Can i have any step by step tutorials for doing this...

Comment: I added a php tutorial. This is not the same as .htaccess, you dont do .htaccess step by step as such...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create anything seperate, but you would need to include the following in the application:

1. Method to recognize WHICH subdomain is loaded (en.domain.com) for english language selection, etc.
2. Create aliases for your domain (or just do a *.domain.com under apache for instance) to funnel the new subdomains into the proper virtual host.
3. Create content specific to the subdomains (you can have one DB but pull distinct data based on which domain is being used -- again you would need to check for this in your app).

Comment: Can i have any step by step tutorials for doing this... Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What would you like step-by-step for?  This is your project, for the domain aliasing search for "Apache domain alias for virtual host" or if you are using IIS, do a similar search. I can't give you a step by step guide, I can only outline how to get to where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a conditional code that checks `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` variable somewhere and set the appropriate database settings based on the variable, without duplicating the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ... if possible, Can i have any step by step tutorials for doing this...